How can I parse a bare "null" response from the server with kotlinx.serialization?
I have a retrofit api interface with a method that looks like this:
   @GET("/data")
   suspend fun getData(): DataDto?

The server in this instance is returning a 200, and the json response body is null (bare string, no quotes).
This results in an exception:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Unexpected JSON token at offset 0: Expected start of the object '{', but had 'n' instead at path: $
JSON input: null

I don't think I change the backend at this point.  Is there any way to get this to work?
I'm using kotlin 2.0.0, kotlinx.serialization gradle plugin 2.0.0, and kotlinx-serialization-json 1.7.1.
My json config looks like this:
    @OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideJson(): Json = Json {
        allowTrailingComma = true
        encodeDefaults = true
        explicitNulls = false
        ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        prettyPrint = true
        isLenient = true
    }

I've tried with explicitNulls set to both true and false, makes no difference.

Instead of returning DataDto?, consider changing the return type to Unit or a custom empty object class. Other option is to Modify API Method Return Type to Any.

kotlinx.serialization should be able to handle a bare null. What version of kotlinx.serialization are you using?

@BobSmith - what would accomplish? Just because in this case, for this user it returns null, it doesn't always return null - and when it doesn't, I need to make use of the DataDto.

@RickyMo - added details to the question.

I think the issue is on retrofit. They probably didn't eventually pass a nullable type to Json.decodeFromString. You can try using gson converter see if that work instead.

Heh, gson is like shooting yourself in the foot with kotlin.  You'll get nulls where you don't expect them, and NPEs along with them.  Been there, done that, it's a bad combination.

I've got a couple different options: 1) Use an interceptor and rewrite the response.  Bad, because it's gziped, and I don't want to have to intercept and unzip everything to find the null.
2) create a custom serializer that will handle this - bad because I'll have to create one and set on every object that's a top-level nullable returned by my api.
3) Use a custom retrofit converter. Again, bad because I'd have to create and register a custom one for each class.
It seems really odd/bad that kotlinx.serialization doesn't appear to handle this.

@BobSmith it's not a retrofit issue. retrofit passes the string "null" to kotlinx.serialization. kotlinx.serialization is expecting an {}, and blows up.

After going down several different rabbit holes, I finally looked at the json.asConverterFactory(contentType) source. There's a FormatString class, that has a method like this:
        override fun <T> fromResponseBody(
            loader: DeserializationStrategy<T>,
            body: ResponseBody
        ): T {
            val string = body.string()
            return format.decodeFromString(loader, string)
        }

This takes a string, decodes it, and returns an instance of T - it doesn't allow a "null" response - it always expects an object. It requires copying a fair bit of code, and modifying things to accept a T?, and a very small change to the fromResponseBody method to check the string value for "null" before forwarding it on to the decodeFromString.
So now I can do json.asNullableConverterFactory(contentType), and it works as intended.
